# Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation in SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-studio

I have a problem working in Azure Data Studio. In SQL Server Management Studio my problem can be fixed with a change to Tools >> Options >> Designers >> Table and Database Designers >> Uncheck – Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation. But I can't find any similar in Azure Data Studio. I can only use Azure Data Studio and docker because of my mac.

Can anyone help me with this setting in Azure Data Studio?  Or is there a way I can adjust the indentity specification for a table that already has data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation** Option comes under Table design.

Currently, this feature is not available in **Azure Data Studio**.

[image]

Use SQL Server Management Studio for this feature.

You can go through this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15#feature-comparison-with-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) to learn more on when to use Azure Data Studio and when to use SQL Server Management Studio for different features.

Comment: Thank you anyway.